# clubbing multiple "With" clauses in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle database 10g and trying to compute the Upper control limit and lower control limit for the data set.Though it seems useless for phone number values but I am just trying to use it as a learning experience.The output should have a row wise form for entries of:-
**salutation,zip,lcl and ucl** value 
which would allow better understanding of data.

```
with q as(

 select student_id,salutation,zip,first_name,last_name from tempTable)

 with r as(

 select avg(phone) as average,stddev(phone) as sd from tempTable)

 select salutation,zip,average-3*sd as"lcl",average+3*sd as"UCL"

from
q ,r
```

error given is **select statement missing**.Please tell me what is wrong I am a sql newbie and can't do it myself

Comment: Query's syntax is wrong: with q as(
select student_id,salutation,zip,first_name,last_name from tempTable),
r as(
select avg(phone) as average,stddev(phone) as sd from tempTable)
select salutation,zip,average-3*sd as"lcl",average+3*sd as"UCL"
from q ,r. then link(s) between q and r is(are) missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while using `stacked CTE` expect for the first `CTE` you don't need `With` keyword instead use `comma` before the `CTE` name. Try this syntax.

```
WITH q 
     AS (SELECT student_id, 
                salutation, 
                zip, 
                first_name, 
                last_name 
         FROM   temptable), 
     r 
     AS (SELECT Avg(phone)    AS average, 
                STDDEV(phone) AS sd 
         FROM   temptable) 
SELECT salutation, 
        zip, 
        average - 3 * sd AS"lcl", 
        average + 3 * sd AS"UCL" 
FROM   q Cross Join r;
```

Comment: yes it worked fine thank you. Is there some better way to achieve the same?

Comment: @chinmay -If you add sample data and expected output it will be easy to find the better way

Comment: I was just hoping to find a general way to compute ucl and lcl values for a table and then display it as a column entry along with all the data in the table, much like what we just did with this table

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a `WITH` clause at all to run such a query. It might be better to use the `AVG()` and `STDDEV()` functions as window functions (analytic functions in Oracle lingo):

```
SELECT temp1.*, average - 3 * sd AS lcl, average + 3 * sd AS ucl
  FROM (
    SELECT student_id, salutation, zip, first_name, last_name
         , AVG(phone) OVER ( ) AS average, STDDEV(phone) OVER ( ) AS sd
      FROM tempTable
) temp1
```

You don't even need the subquery but it helps save some keystrokes. See [this SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39870) with dummy data from `DUAL`.

P.S. You do need the alias (in this case, `temp1`) for the subquery if you want to use `*` to get all the columns selected in the subquery - it won't work otherwise. Alternately you could name the columns explicitly, which is a good practice anyway.